# Multithread calculate mean and std does not improve efficiency

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing

I am a novice in the field of C++ multithread programming and I try to use multithread to compute the mean and standard deviation of my data in parallel to reduce the cost of time. My function of calculation of mean and standard deviation is as the following.

```
void cal_mean_std(float* data, float* mean, float* sd, int N, int start_index, int span_cols)
{
    int value;
    for(int j = start_index; j < start_index + span_cols; j++){
        mean[j] = 0;
        sd[j] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            value = data[j * N + i];
            mean[j] += value;
            sd[j] += value * value;
        }
        mean[j] = mean[j] / N;
        sd[j] = sqrt(sd[j] / N - mean[j] * mean[j]);
    }
}
```

I specify the start index and calculation spans of each thread and I activate my thread_pool as the following.

```
    x.mean = new float[x.M];
    x.sd = new float[x.M];
    std::vector<std::thread> thread_pool;

    int h = 4;
    thread_pool.reserve(h);
    int SNIPs = static_cast<int>(x.M / h + 1);
    int SNIPs_final = x.M - (h - 1) * SNIPs;
     for (int i = 0; i < h - 1; i++)
     {
         thread_pool.push_back(std::thread(std::bind(cal_mean_std, x.data, x.mean, x.sd,
                                                 x.N, i*SNIPs, SNIPs)));
     }
    thread_pool.push_back(std::thread(std::bind(cal_mean_std, x.data, x.mean, x.sd,
                                                 x.N, (h-1)*SNIPs, SNIPs_final)));
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
        thread_pool.at(i).join();
```

where the `x.M` is the total number of cols of my data. However, I found that implement in this way did not improve the program efficiency. I am not sure what the problem is.

Actually, we can simulate data to do the computation. My data size is 5k x 300k. The sequential calculation by using for loop all over the data one thread takes 15 seconds. My multithreading version sometimes takes 16 seconds.

The simulation code is as the following and I find that when I use h = 1, the program takes 6s to finish. However, when I use h = 4, the program takes 14s to finish.

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

void gen_matrix(int N, int P, float* data){
    for (int i = 0; i < N * P; i++)
    {
        data[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
}

void cal_mean_std(float* data, float* mean, float* sd, int N, int start_index, int span_cols)
{
    int value;
    for(int j = start_index; j < start_index + span_cols; j++){
        mean[j] = 0;
        sd[j] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            value = data[j * N + i];
            mean[j] += value;
            sd[j] += value * value;
        }
        mean[j] = mean[j] / N;
        sd[j] = sqrt(sd[j] / N - mean[j] * mean[j]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N = 5000;
    int P = 300000;
    float* data = new float[N*P];
    gen_matrix(N, P, data);
    float* mean = new float[P];
    float* std = new float[P];
    std::vector<std::thread> thread_pool;
    clock_t t1;
    t1 = clock();
    int h = 1;
    thread_pool.reserve(h);
    int SNIPs = static_cast<int>(P / h + 1);
    int SNIPs_final = P - (h - 1) * SNIPs;
    for (int i = 0; i < h - 1; i++)
    {
        thread_pool.push_back(std::thread(std::bind(cal_mean_std, data, mean, std,
                                                    N, i*SNIPs, SNIPs)));
    }
    thread_pool.push_back(std::thread(std::bind(cal_mean_std, data, mean, std,
                                                N, (h-1)*SNIPs, SNIPs_final)));
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
        thread_pool.at(i).join();
    std::cout <<"Time for the cal mean and std is " << (clock() - t1) * 1.0/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186926/discussion-on-question-by-sean-c-11-multithread-calculate-mean-and-std-does-no).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, everyone. Finally, I found what the problem is with my code. The timer `clock_t` computes the CPU consumption time instead of wall time.